# Mule:Filtering a message if database select query does'nt return a row

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have this requirement of consuming a message from message broker and then filtering message in next stage if certain database select query does not return a row. what is the best way to achieve this in mule.Do i need to create a custom filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by ->

`jdbc:inbound-endpoint` -> 'enritcher(jdbc:outbound-endpoint, setting flowvar 'shouldBeFiltered')' -> expression-filter(based on the value of the flowvar 'shouldBeFiltered').